# Filtering list if date is null or not using Linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of objects as shown below in which date could be null,

```
List<SomeObjects> myList:
myList[0] = id:1, Date:3/3/2016
myList[1] = id:2, Date:NULL
myList[2] = id:3, Date:3/3/2016
myList[3] = id:4, Date:NULL
```

For one condition I have to sort this list as per date as shown:

```
var comparingDays = DateTime.Today; 
var resultsFrom = "past 7 days";
comparingDays.AddDays(-7);                      
myList.Where(t =>t.Date.HasValue ? Convert.ToDateTime(t.Date) >= comparingDays : ).ToList();
```

If Date is null I don't need those results, but I am struggling how to proceed in the false condition of HasValue here.

Comment: use `DateTime.MaxValue` or `DateTime.MinValue`.

Comment: Side note, use `comparingDays = comparingDays.AddDays(-7);`

Comment: what type is `t.Date` ?  If it's a string then the answers below are all invalid.

Comment: Is `Date` a `DateTime` property then why are you using `Convert.ToDateTime`? Is it a String ? Then how are u using `Date.HasValue` ? There is something wrong here.

Answer (score 3):

If "Date" is a DateTime?, you can change your query like so :

```
myList
  .Where(t =>t.Date.HasValue && t.Date.Value >= comparingDays).ToList()
```

So your null dates will be filtered and then you can safely compare the date value.

Answer (score 2):

A Combination of `Where`(filter) and `OrderBy` (sort) should work:

```
List<SomeObjects> results = myList.Where(t => t.Date.HasValue && t.Date >= comparingDays)
                                   .OrderBy(t => t.Date).ToList();
```

Comment: The Sorting was in the title but not in the question.

Answer (score 1):

When t.Date is a DateTime (the Convert throws doubt on that), you can simply use

```
// myList
// .Where(t =>t.Date.HasValue ? Convert.ToDateTime(t.Date) >= comparingDays :)
// .ToList();

myList.Where(t => t.Date >= comparingDays).ToList()
```

Because `null` is not greater (or smaller) than any Date value.